# PHP PDO Error [Call to undefined method PDOStatement]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp, prepared-statement

Hi I cant get my query to return any values from database.
I have this function:

```
 private function Query($sql, $arg){
    require "conection.php"; 
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute($arg);
    $result = $q->get_result();
    return $result;
}
```

I've tried many different PDO statements but all give the same error code [Call to undefined method PDOStatement] I've tried binding results, fetch all... etc but nothing works..
This is my conection.php:

```
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$dbname = "truckla";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456";
try{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
   }catch(Exception $e){die("Fatal error: ".$e->getMessage());}
```

This is the following query and how Im calling it:

```
$result = $this->Query("SELECT OrderId,Products,Quantis,Description,RecvrName,AddressInfo,GPS,TimeStart,TimeSpec FROM orders WHERE IsPrivate LIKE 'false' AND IsComplete LIKE 'false' AND StillOpen LIKE 'true' AND CanShow LIKE 'true' AND TruckType LIKE '%?%' OR ((GroupId LIKE '%?%' OR DriversId LIKE '%?%') AND IsComplete LIKE 'false' AND StillOpen LIKE 'true' AND CanShow LIKE 'true')", array($trucktype,$groupsId,$driverId));
```

The query works fine in phpMyAdmin and I can get the values if i call it like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);
```

But I dont trust in escaping bad chars and just run the query, how can I call the query and get the values! Is it a configuration error because no PDO statement is valid... Im using PHP 7.2.10, MySQL and XAMPP 3.2.2 thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the line of code where this error actually happens.

Comment: `get_result`? Try calling something like `fetch` or `fetchAll` or some other method that a `PDOStatement` supports. Read the manual at https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php.

Comment: The error happens when calling get_result and its the same error when i call fetch or fetchAll

Comment: Hi there I just made it work! I was debugging my code incorrecly... and fetchAll() was indeed working correclty but returned an empty array... that other problem was because the use of wildcards in the prepared statement. i fixed it by appending the wildcard when passing the arguments to the prepared statement

Comment: `$wildcardVar = "%".$normalVar."%":`